# How to make end portal?! Help?! Tried every way?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

this is a photo of the “correct” way of doing it, apparently, even though it’s not working.

[image]

Comment: "In Creative mode, the player can create their own portal but it will only activate if all of the end portal frames were placed with the **front facing inward**, i.e. placed with the player standing inside the ring and directly in front of the frame they are placing. " - Did you do this?

Comment: @TimmyJim As you can see from the picture, ALL of the frames are facing inwards.

Comment: I did this, yes.

Comment: You might try elevating them by one block?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you can't construct an end portal in a superflat world. **It should work** **perfectly fine in a normally generated world**. Generate a normal world, then construct your end portal, but remove the lava. If it doesn't work, try elevating it up 3 blocks into the air.